# How to save text files or excel files in local folder in windows phone

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, download

How to save text files or excel files in local folder in windows phone?
I get the text files from web service response from http url,
but how do I save them in a local folder?
For more ideas see my code below.
Thanks!!

```
Uri uri = new Uri("https://abcd/xyz/def");
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
wc.DownloadStringCompleted += wc_DownloadStringCompleted;

void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
        string result = e.Result.ToString();

        MessageBox.Show(result);

        IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        string FolderName = "localFolder\\myData\\";
        myIsolatedStorage.CreateDirectory(FolderName);
        string filepath = System.IO.Path.Combine(FolderName, "myfile.txt");

        using (StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(new  IsolatedStorageFileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, myIsolatedStorage)))
        {
            write.WriteLine(result);
            write.Close();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to write .txtFile:

```
 void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            String response = e.Result.ToString();
            IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication(); 
            //Set File Path  
             string FolderName = "localFolder\\myData\\";
             myIsolatedStorage.CreateDirectory(FolderName);
             string FilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(FolderName, "myFile.txt"); 

            //create new file
            using (StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter(new  IsolatedStorageFileStream(FilePath , FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, myIsolatedStorage)))
            {       
             writeFile.WriteLine(response);
             writeFile.Close();
            }
        }
```

And check file is saved or not:

```
if (myIsolatedStorage.DirectoryExists("localFolder\\myData\\"))
{
String[] fileNames = myIsolatedStorage.GetFileNames("localFolder\\myData\\*");
}
```

Comment: file would be saved in isolated storage you could provide path where you want to save your files

Comment: where should I specify path.please mention..I dont know..thanks!!

Comment: thanks and give me one suggestion that how should I display also Excel files and Doc files in windows phone emulator?

Comment: @ I updated code with file path....but as per my knowlege to show a excel file or doc file in wp is procedural...for this you have to do some goole

Comment: it is returning error and error is that "operation is not Permitted on FileStream"

Comment: @Viraj have you find above updated code working for you

Comment: I am working on it brother, but in my local folder, file is not saving. Wanna see my updated code??

Comment: why are you going to save these files in local folder.....use above code that would save your files in "localFolder\\myData\\" location...and when you needed these files use same path.

Comment: code which you have posted what problem you are facing

Comment: I want to know that the folder name you gave in the code, should I write the same folder name, if yes then where do I find this folder?

Comment: yes....you could give any name which you want ....in my case your file would be saved  in "localFolder\\myData\\" location

Comment: thanks man for your continuous help..but last point is that I am not getting this directory,where do I find it?

Comment: i have posted the code to get file names from saved location

Comment: I have used that code but "localFolder\\mydata" Directory is not creating.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier,that code for creating directory is not working for me,that code is not creating directory, then how to solve?

Comment: if code is not working what exception you are getting

Comment: I am not getting any exception and not getting directory..thanks!!